# Apache2.4 not calling my custom plugin with "require all granted" directive

Tags: authentication, plugins, apache2.4

I have installed Apache webserver version 2.4. We have a webserver plugin which is developed in c++ and is deployed on this webserver. This plugin does the job of authentication and authorization of users.

Issue is if I use :

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

Gives 500 internal server error

Require all granted

My module is NOT called

Please suggest me an apache24 directive which would call my module without giving interal server error